# Python: small while loop error

Tags: python, loops, syntax, conditional-statements

Im new to python and programming in general and I came across this problem while fiddling around with a simple while loop. The loop takes input to evaluate two possible passwords:

```
    print('Enter password')
    passEntry = input()

    while passEntry !='juice' or 'juice2':
      print('Access Denied')
      passEntry = input()
      print(passEntry)

    print('Access Granted')
```

It doesnt seem to be accepting juice or juice2 as valid.

Also just accepting one password like:

```
    while passEntry != 'juice' :
```

will not work, while:

```
    while passEntry !='juice' :
```

works fine. I cant seem to find the reason for these issues (Only difference between the latter two is the space after the =). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This may not reason of error I guess!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should use Python's [getpass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) module to get a password portably. For example:

```
import getpass
passEntry = getpass.getpass("Enter password")
```

Then, the code you have written to guard the `while` loop:

```
while passEntry != 'juice' or 'juice2':
```

gets interpreted by the Python interpreter as a while loop with the guard expression

```
(passEntry != 'juice') or 'juice2'
```

This is always true because regardless of whether `passEntry` equals "juice" or not, "juice2" will be considered as true when interpreted as a boolean.

In Python, the best way to test membership is to use the [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), which works for a variety of data types such as a list or a set or a tuple. For example, a list:

```
while passEntry not in ['juice', 'juice2']:
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
while passEntry not in ['juice' ,'juice2']:
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
while passEntry !='juice' and passEntry!= 'juice2':
```

and using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`?

`input()` evaluates the input as if it were Python code.

Comment: Yes this was it for the first part, made logical error using or instead of and. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`passEntry !='juice' or 'juice2'` means `(pass != 'juice') or ('juice2')`.  `"juice2"` is a nonempty string, so it is always true.  Thus your condition is always true.

You want to do `passEntry != 'juice' and passEntry != 'juice2'`, or more nicely `passEntry not in ('juice', 'juice2')`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
while passEntry !='juice' and passEntry !='juice2':
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the way you wrote the while statement.

```
while passEntry !='juice' or 'juice2':
```

That line will always be true, when read by the python interpreter.
And also instead of:

```
passEntry = input()
```

Use:

```
passEntry = raw_input()
```

(Unless you are using Python 3)

the `input` in Python 2 evals your input.

This will be the proper code:

```
print('Enter password')
passEntry = raw_input()

while passEntry != 'juice' and passEntry != 'juice2':
    print('Access Denied')
    passEntry = raw_input()
    print(passEntry)

print('Access Granted')
```

Comment: Ok, im running python3, so i guess thats why raw_input() gave me problems. Thanks